# Change the value of a text input element prior to submit using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, dynamics-365

The `first_name` is changed to Hello but George is still written to the database on submit of the form. How can I update the value of the text field prior to submitting the form.  This is being done on a portal for a dynamics 365 project and when submitted the data is being written to a common data service database.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UpdateButton').click(function(){
        alert($('#first_name').val()); // value is George
        $('#first_name').val("Hello"); // change to Hello
        alert($('#first_name').val()); // value is Hello
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML so we can help you. We need to see a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can add `$("#first_name").trigger("change");` after you set the value with `.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had do so smilar work, to calculate fields input and change values to other fields becuase the Business rules are not triggered on Portal forms.
When you add custom fuction to the default Update/Submmit buttton on Portal form it is skipped, therefor I've done as followed and you can try the same:

- Use JS/JQuery to hide the default button;
- Add a custom button that looks exactly as the default;
- On the custom button click call the function you need for changing values and any other updates that you need to do on background;
- As final step trigger the default Update/Submmit buttton;